# ...anxieties about us/our having any more downtime

Tags: prepositions, possessives, subjects, possessive-pronouns

In some cases that a pronoun is a subject which is followed by a verb follows a preposition.

Then the subject is changed into possessive determiners.

But I read a sentence A.

> A. On the other there's a set of anxieties about **us** having any more downtime

I wonder about the subject. Should it be changed to **our** such as B?

> B. On the other there's a set of anxieties about **our** having any more downtime,

What is the differencebetween A and B? Right or wrong? Formal or informal?